# The custom reusable <Button> component works in one case while dosent in another (React Native)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am unable to see my  component for the "Log Out" aspect.
It is not entirely invisible, but instead of a block style just a single line is visible with no text.
However, The same reusable Button component works with the "Log In button".

```
renderContent() {
    switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
        case true:
            return <Button> Log Out </Button>;
        case false:
            return <LoginForm />;
        default:
            return <Spinner size="large" />;
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Header headerText="Authentication" />
            {this.renderContent()}
        </View>
    );
```

when the user is not logged in the output is as follows:
[the dark blue line below the Authentication header is the](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTt4h.jpg)

[However, The same Button with "Log In" works well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg3Sh.jpg)

I have tried to render a text component in place of the button component and it also works. Seems like just the Button in this particular conditional rendering is not working!

My Button component:

```
const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => {
const { buttonStyle, buttonTextStyle } = styles;
console.log({ children });
return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
        <Text style={buttonTextStyle}>
            {children}
        </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

};

the code block where Log In works:

```
renderButton() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
        return <Spinner size="small" />
    }

    return (
        <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
            Log In
        </Button>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code block where it works with "Log In" case?

Comment: Button has special property for text in it. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button. In your case it should be <Button title='Log out' />

Comment: @FarukYazıcı, Please look at the edited problem.

Comment: @RomanOsypov i am rendering the text as 'children' passed within <Button></Button>. Please see the code for my button component for better understanding.